# Activating one button also affects the other?

Tags: html, css, sass

Here's the demo: https://jsfiddle.net/krycLxb0/

The way this is set up is so that to create the illusion that the button is pressed, the padding of the outer container (.button) is changed, making the top padding more than the bottom.  However, when this is activated, the other button seems to shrink down as well. Why does this happen, and how do I fix it?

Here's the source:

```css
header {
  letter-spacing: .04em;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.button {
  padding: 4px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: 300ms ease;
  will-change: auto;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-shadow: 0px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.button span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10em;
  padding: 1.2em;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: #FF4A50;
}

.button:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.button:active {
  transition: none;
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
}

.button--filled {
  background: #BC2E56;
  color: white;
}

.button--filled span {
  background: #FF4A50;
}

.button--dark {
  background: rgba(65, 57, 76, 0.6);
}

.button--dark span {
  background: #FFF8F2;
}
```

```html
<header>

  <a class="button button--filled" href="#"><span>Get Started</span></a>
  <a class="button button--dark" href="#"><span>Learn more</span></a>

</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your buttons are now `vertical-align: baseline`. Just add `vertical-align: top;` to your `.button`. See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/krycLxb0/1/)